# modify uploaded image and then submit modified image in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

i have an HTML form with a file input that accepts images. now what i would like to accomplish is, i will take take the image the user uploads and make some changes to it using javascript and then i want to submit the modified image and not the original one.
so basically change the value of the file input. but i have read that updating the value of a file input is not possible so is there anyway i could work around this?

keep in mind that i do not have full access to the backend. so the only way for me to pass the image to the backend is through the form.

any help is appreciated! thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is can be done by transferring the uploaded image to a canvas element  and then modifying the canvas.

```js
// Wait until the file input is changed
document.getElementById("image_input").onchange = function() {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        // Create canvas which will the image to be modified
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      
      // Set canvas size to image size
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      
      // Add circle
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
      
      // Display the canvas for visualizing purposes
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      
        // Set the motified image to be content when the form is submited. 
      document.getElementById("modified_image").value = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");      
    }
    image.src = reader.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="file" id="image_input" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg">
  <input id="modified_image" name="image" type="hidden" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

In the above example, an image is uploaded, modified using canvas properties, and then a form input is changed to the content of the modified image.

If you would like to learn how to make custom image modifications using canvas, I suggest you perform some research on Google.

Best regards,

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much.
at first i was only thinking about it from the perspective of sharing the updated file itself, and i haven't thought about just sharing the file link. now it works perfectly.